# How to find each black bar's begin and end row numbers?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

[image: Black bars with begin and end row numbers]

A `cv::Mat` binarized image. 
Find row numbers of each black bar in vertical direction.

Comment: Interesting problem. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you asking to calculate the length of each black pixel in the image you can calculate the length by scanning the image with pointers. when we use pointers to an image the pointer points to the first row. Here is the code

```
Mat image; //this is the image that contain the above image;
int numberOfRow=image.rows;//number of rows in the image
int length[4];
int forTheFirstTime=0;
int index=0;
int a=0;
for(int j=0;j<numberOfRow;j++)
{
  uchar* data=image.ptr<uchar>(j);//the pointer to each row in the image
  if(data[0]==0) //if the pixel at the first is black
  {
    a++;  
  }
  if(data[0]==1)
  {
    if(forTheFirstTime==0)//if the white pixel is for the first time
    {
      length[index]=a;
      a=0;
      index++
    }
    else
    {
      //do nothing
    }
  }
}
```

for more search google Scanning image with pointers.

Comment: Thanks for letting know about `image.ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

`img` is the given image in the question.

I coded like this.

```
Mat img_inv;
bitwise_not(img, img_inv);

int totalrows = img_inv.rows;
int totalcols = img_inv.cols;

int hist[totalrows];
int blackspacecount = 0;
bool isbackground = true;

for(int i=0; i<totalrows; i++)
{
    hist[i] = countNonZero(img_inv(Rect(0,i,totalcols,1)));

    if(hist[i] > 0)
    {
        if(isbackground == true)
        {
            blackspacecount++;
            isbackground = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isbackground = true;
    }
}



int blackspaces[blackspacecount][2];

int p = 0;

for(int i=1; i<totalrows; i++)
{
    if ( hist[i] > 0 && hist[i-1] == 0)
    {
        blackspaces[p][0] = i;    // Begin
    }
    if ( hist[i] == 0 && hist[i-1] > 0)
    {
        blackspaces[p][1] = i-1;    // End
        p++;
    }
}
```

Any other ways?